Compare bit bucket branches and see differences that should not be seen
I have the following branches

uat
prep
prod

I have same code in all 3 branches.
When I compare UAT as Source and PREP as Destination, bitbucket shows no differences.
however, If I compare UAT as destination and PREP as source, there are so many differences.
What explains this behavior?
Tried to do a rebase and wanted to ensure that there are no differences.

What command or tool do you use ?

Sounds a bit like different commits are compared.

If you mean the web UI, it only shows changes that are in the source branch, but not in the target branch. So UAT has no new changes to PREP, while PREP does against UAT thus showing the missing changes

Well, UAT is merged to PREP. So, technically, there should be no changes between PREP and UAT right?

Your PREP branch must have received more commits after the UAT is merged to it. Do remember the bitbucket uses a 3 dot diff which is basically a comparison between the commit where the feature branch was last synched with the destination branch and the most recent version of the feature branch.
